# Best way to remove the first elements from each list in a list of lists in Prolog?

Tags: list, data-structures, prolog

I am trying to remove the first element of every list in a list of lists.
For example,  to list [[1,2],[3,4]], I should return [[2],[4]].
In most situations, this code below will work fine:

```
remove_firstElem([],[]). 
remove_firstElem([[_H|T]|Ls],[T|L]) :-
    remove_firstElem(Ls,L).
```

But for lists like [[1],[2]], I would like it to return [] rather than [[],[]].

What I tried so far looks like:

```
remove_firstElem([_H|Ls],L) :-
    length(_H,1),
    remove_firstElem(Ls,L).
```

But it returns `[ ],[[ ]],[[ ]],[[ ],[ ]]` and I really don't know what's wrong with it.

Can anyone help me to fix it? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What if there is an empty list in the source. Like `remove_firstElem([[]],L)`.

Comment: to [ [ ] ] it should return [ ],  there should be  no empty list in the list it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to pop the head of the list, but in case the list contains only one element (or none at all), that list should be removed.

We can check if the sublist contains at least two elements with the pattern:

```
pop_lists([[_,H2|T]|TA],[[H2|T]|TB]) :-
    pop_lists(TA,TB).
```

so here we have a pattern `[_,H2|T]` for the first list. The `_` binds with the first element, `H2` with the second element, and the remaining elements with the tail.

Lists that can not unify with that pattern are the empty list, or a list with one element. So in that case we simply ignore them:

```
pop_lists([[]|TA],TB) :-
    pop_lists(TA,TB).
pop_lists([[_]|TA],TB) :-
    pop_lists(TA,TB).
```

In case we reach the end of the list, of course we unify the filter with the empty list as well:

```
pop_list([],[]).
```

we better put this clause on the first line to make our predicate more multidirectional. So in full, we have the following solution:

```
pop_list([],[]).
pop_list([[_,H2|T]|TA],[[H2|T]|TB]) :-
    pop_list(TA,TB).
pop_list([[]|TA],TB) :-
    pop_list(TA,TB).
pop_list([[_]|TA],TB) :-
    pop_list(TA,TB).
```

We can further reorder the statements, such that the amount of backtracking is less:

```
pop_list([],[]).
pop_list([[]|TA],TB) :-
    pop_list(TA,TB).
pop_list([[_]|TA],TB) :-
    pop_list(TA,TB).
pop_list([[_,H2|T]|TA],[[H2|T]|TB]) :-
    pop_list(TA,TB).
```

Comment: Thanks，really a smart and clear solution.  But it returns [ ] and false to list such as [ [1],[2] ], is there any way to avoid that false?

Comment: @Fallin: that is actually the same. The `false` is only because Prolog needs to try other clauses (in search for another answer). Since that fails, it says false. So basically it says: "*an answer is `[]`, and there is no other answer*"

Comment: @Fallin: by reordering the clauses, we can probably avoid it :)

Comment: @Fallin You can probably get rid of them using a few `if_/3` from [`library(reif)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl).

Answer (score 0):

Easier way:

```
list_tail([_|Es], Es).
maplist(list_tail, Input, Output).
```